# Binary search using javascript

Tags: javascript, binary-search

I am converting c++ code into javascript that is [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-monotonically-increasing-subsequence-size-n-log-n/). The rest of the code looks fine but following function has a problem. First, second line inside while loop throws error `Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`. When I change that to `m = (A[m] >= key ? r : l);` then this loop becomes infinite. **How can I solve it in javascript?**

```
    function CeilIndex(A, l, r, key) {
        var m;

        while( r - l > 1 ) {
            m = l + (r - l)/2;
            (A[m] >= key ? r : l) = m; // ternary expression returns an l-value
        }

        return r;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (A[m] >= key) {
    r = m;
} else {
    l = m;
}
```

JavaScript can't have variable lvalues except for properties (i.e. you could do `obj[A[m] >= key ? 'r' : 'l'] = m`, but not what you're proposing).

Answer (score 1):

You just need to break out your left-side properly. I don't know what you're trying to do, but assuming you're assigning `m` to either `r` or `l`:

```
if (A[m] >= key) {
    r = m;
} else {
    l = m;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript you can do this instead:

```
A[m] >= key ? r = m : l = m;
```